# Ehcache non-transactional context with transactional cache

Tags: configuration, transactions, ehcache

I have Ehcache cache instance configured as `transactionalMode="local"`.
Now, when I try to put an element in said cache outside of a transaction, I get
`net.sf.ehcache.transaction.TransactionException: transaction not started`.

Does this mean that every call on transactional cache instance needs to be in a transaction context?
I'm doing some custom cache pre-loading on startup, and I don't want Ehcache transaction (and copyOnRead/Write) overhead. Also, since I'll be dealing with logically immutable objects, I'd like to be able to read them from cache without transaction scope, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use local transaction in the first place? i.e. do you need to put multiple cache entries atomically in a single operation? 
In any case, if you use transactionalMode="local", you're kind of stuck having to perform all your cache operations within a transaction boundary (even reads)

But if you need more granularity, I'd recommend you look at ehcache explicit locking which can be used as a custom alternative to XA Transactions or Local transactions (without having to specify transactionalMode in your ehcache config). More at http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/explicitlocking

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need a global transaction of sorts, without full-blown JTA. That's why I'm mostly interested in Local transaction's rollback mechanism. I'd simply rollback all cache changes in case "global transaction" fails. And yes, I'm dealing with multiple cache levels that need to stay consistent. So locking will come in handy from isolation point of view, but it looks like I'd still need to implement rollback myself, right?